# Can't build android module

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium

Information about my build environment:

- Mac OS 10.11.2
- Ti SDK 5.3.0.GA
- Ti CLI 5.0.8
- Android 23
- Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.9.2v20140221-1700

I'm trying to build this module [tiadbuddiz-android](https://github.com/Astrovic/tiadbuddiz), but the terminal gives me this error message:
[terminal log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeZAQ.png)

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 5.0.8, Titanium SDK version 5.3.0.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/

[ERROR] Unable to compile project because the 'sdk-version' in the tiapp.xml is not installed

The project's sdk-version is currently set to 3.2.0.GA, which is not installed.

Update the sdk-version in the tiapp.xml to one of the installed Titaniums SDKs:
    3.5.2.v20160311103211
    4.1.1.v20160311104258
    5.1.1.GA
    5.1.2.GA
    5.2.0.GA
    5.2.2.GA
    5.3.0.GA
or run 'titanium sdk install 3.2.0.GA' to download and install Titanium SDK 3.2.0.GA
```

Comment: I'm also getting this error. I've tried to compile using 5.2.2.GA and 5.3.0.GA, with a old module and a new one. I don't have any tiapp or timodule file at the workspace root or module root. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The titanium sdk version set in your project is 3.2.0.GA but you are trying to build with 5.3.0.GA.

Try updating your project version to 5.3.0.GA or instal version 3.2.0.GA

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I did not set anywhere the 'sdk-version'. For this I do not understand why this error appears.
In my **build.properties** I set the SDK 5.3.0.GA

Comment: I receive this error too: [error image](https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/attachment/59542/Schermata%202016-06-09%20alle%2012.39.42.png)

Answer (score 0):

After two days of hell, I have found the cause of my problem! In my workspace root there was an old tiapp.xml (I do not know how it got there...). After removing it, I managed to make the build of the modules, both from Appcelerator Studio that from the CLI.